# stop IP address to land on website home page

Tags: ubuntu, php, webserver, htaccess

I notices that when i type my VPS IP address in address bar then it display website home page. So it may case duplicate content.

Can you please tell me How to stop IP address landing on website home page.

UPDATE :

I want to restrict direct IP access to website.

Suppose my VPS IP address is 1.2.3.4 and my website address is example.com.

I can access my website using both IP and website address. So I want to restrict direct IP access to website.

I think Now it's clear.

Comment: Please check http://serverfault.com/questions/607137/restrict-direct-ip-access-to-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either set-up another VirtualHost within Apache/Nginx (or whatever your webserver is) which points to a blank or default index page so that is shown when going to your servers IP address.

Alternatively you could drop the following mod_rewrite rule into your Apache configuration or .htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Obviously replacing www.yourdomain.com with your actual domain name.

Comment: I have already 3 VirtualHost, default/first VirtualHost is just blank page, but IP is landing on second/other VirtualHost. How to set landing on first VirtualHost ?. i know that i can apply using php **if http_host = IP > redirect on a domain**, or using htaacess but i want to configure in server. And i want to know which is doing so in server.

Comment: Is the other VirtualHost running off of a different IP address? Can you confirm you are running Apache? If so can you post the output of ```httpd -S``` command.

Comment: I am using VESTA control panel so it installed both Apache and Nginx. Apache for Hosting and Nginx for default/caching.

Comment: All VirtualHost are running on same IP.